# MySQL: CAST requires no space before parenthesis?

Tags: mysql, function, casting

In MySQL 5.1, why won't this SQL work correctly?

```
SELECT CAST (20091023 as date);
```

*[I've just figured out the answer to this question myself-- and I'll answer it myself below-- but the behavior was so odd that I wanted to capture it as a StackOverflow Q&A pair so others won't waste time on the same problem.]*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code works: (note the space is removed after "CAST")

```
SELECT CAST(20091023 as date);
```

Turns out MySQL requires that a specific list of built-in functions have no spaces between the function name and the parenthesis.  See [this page in the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html) for more info about why this behavior exists.

The following list of functions have the same restriction in MySQL 5.1 (there are many more in previous versions):

```
ADDDATE      
BIT_AND      
BIT_OR       
BIT_XOR      
CAST         
COUNT        
CURDATE      
CURTIME      
DATE_ADD     
DATE_SUB     
EXTRACT      
GROUP_CONCAT 
MAX          
MID          
MIN          
NOW          
POSITION     
SESSION_USER 
STD          
STDDEV       
STDDEV_POP   
STDDEV_SAMP  
SUBDATE      
SUBSTR       
SUBSTRING    
SUM          
SYSDATE      
SYSTEM_USER  
TRIM         
VARIANCE     
VAR_POP      
VAR_SAMP
```

Hope this answer helps you avoid wasting the same amount of time I did on this! :-)