# ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION frozenfood.NOW does not exist?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert Table purchaseOrder and Table customerOrder but the DATE(NOW ()) function wouldn't work.

[Here are the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iuif.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: CAST requires no space before parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812422/mysql-cast-requires-no-space-before-parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a space after NOW.
Change it to NOW() and it will work..